# executing SQL command in a variable using curl

Tags: shell, unix, curl, marklogic

I am trying to write the below curl command against MarkLogic server :-

```
curl --digest -u "${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}" -k -X POST "${URLCALL}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "Accept: text/csv" -d@"{$SELECTQUERY}"
```

But the above command is not working for me. The error i am getting is :

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "{select count(*) from
Warning: db.table1}", this makes an empty POST.
```

where in :

```
USERNAME=admin
PASSWORD=admin
URLCALL="https://localhost:8010/v1/rows"
SELECTQUERY="select count(*) from db.table1"
```

I am trying to execute this curl and run the SQL query inside `SELECTQUERY` variable in my MarkLogic server and I want the count from this query to be sent to a variable also. How can I achieve it?

Comment: is this space in `USERNAME= admin` intentional

Comment: no. its not intentional.

Comment: although the variable assignment is not problematic in my script, what is causing issue is the curl command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the curl data parameter (`-d` or `--data`), if you are setting a string and not a reference to a file path, then remove the `@`.

And if you are sending over SQL statements, then change the `Content-type` from `application/json` to `application/sql`

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/rows

> Content-type
> The MIME type of the request body. Allowed values:

- `application/json` for an Optic query serialized as an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) in JSON format
- `application/vnd.marklogic.querydsl+javascript` for an Optic query represented in JavaScript syntax
- `application/sql` for an SQL SELECT statement
- `application/sparql-query` for a SPARQL SELECT statement

You would want to use:

```
curl --digest -u "${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}" -k -X POST "${URLCALL}" -H "Content-Type: application/sql" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "Accept: text/csv" -d "{$SELECTQUERY}"
```

Comment: {"errorResponse":{"statusCode":400, "status":"Bad Request", "messageCode":"RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ", "message":"RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ: fn.error(null, 'RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ', 'unsupported content type: '+contentType); -- Invalid request:  reason: unsupported content type: application/sql"}} --> I m getting this as the output of above curl command